# Is it possible to store Xamarin Forms Styles in Class library separate from the Class library that houses all the views

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, app.xaml

I have a several Xamarin forms projects that make up a suite of applications.  In each project there is the XF class library with all of my views, viewmodels etc as well as the stub projects for all of the target platforms.

To share common code, views across all of the projects in the suite of applications, I also have a separate class library where I share view / code that are common across all projects in the application suite.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to move all of my style's definitions from the App.xaml file of each project into the class library that is shared across all the projects. The goal is to have one set of styles that can be updated and the update will apply to all projects in the suite of applications.

Any ideas?  I was thinking I might be able to add the programmatically in c# class but I was more looking for a way to have it in XAML so moving from the App.xaml to the new approach would not require a large change to the projects.

Comment: You'll have to research loading/accessing the class library, but once you have that, the technique is to define a custom `ResourceDictionary`. This can be done in XAML. Then in App.xaml.cs, add it to app's dictionary by `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new MyResourceDictionary());`

Comment: check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#stand-alone-resource-dictionaries) doc.

Comment: So similar to how you incorporate theme colors into an app?  If so then doing that I would loose the intelisense from what I have tested.  Unless I am doing something incorrect.

Comment: OK i will check this out again but I am not sure I will still get intelisense for the style properties of controls.